# Stacked column highcharts change x and y

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, highcharts

I'm looking for a charts like this:

[image]

I would like to use the [stacked column charts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked) from the **highcharts library**. But as you can see in the image I need to change the view of the values. But I have no idea to begin with this. Could someone help me on my way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by stacked chart as you mentioed,

```
series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [null, null, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [null,null, 3, 2, 1]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
        }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/72E7y/